# I keep getting Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error with AngularJS.

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to teach myself Angular and I keep getting an error. I wrote a simple bit of code to test out Angular while following a tutorial and I keep getting this error and Angular not doing what it's supposed to do.

```
 angular.min.js:6Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] 
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$injector/modulerr?
0%20%20at%20c%20(http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A8080%2Fangular.min.js%3A20%3A359)(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:6(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:40r @ angular.min.js:7g @ angular.min.js:39db @ angular.min.js:43c @ angular.min.js:20Bc @ angular.min.js:21ge @ angular.min.js:19(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:315b @ angular.min.js:189Sf @ angular.min.js:37d @ angular.min.js:36
```

This is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='store'>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javasciprt" src="app.js"></script>
        <p>{{"hello" + " you"}}</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the JS

```
var app = angular.module('store', []);
```

Comment: I'm using your exact code and not having issues. Can you make sure your app.js path is correct in the script tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in you script tag where including `app.js` -

> text/javasciprt

instead of `text/javascript`

By the way, there is no need to write `text/javascript` at all, according to html5 standard.

Answer (score 0):

**ng-app='store'** give in body tag.

```
<body ng-app='store'> </body>
```